# C++ Builder, copy to clipboard

Tags: c++builder

Trying to copy to Clipboard as I found in Delphi Example, but got error

> [bcc32c Error] Unit1.cpp(40): use of undeclared identifier 'Clipboard'

I connected library Vcl.Clipbrd

```
#include <vcl.h>
#pragma hdrstop
#pragma Vcl.Clipbrd
#include "Unit1.h"
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#pragma package(smart_init)
#pragma resource "*.dfm"
TForm1 *Form1;

.....................

void __fastcall TForm1::Button3Click(TObject *Sender)
{
Clipboard()->AsText=DBLookupListBox12->DataField;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting the error because you did not `#include` the header file that declares the [`Clipboard()`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Clipbrd.Clipboard) function.

You need to remove `#pragma Vcl.Clipbrd`, and instead use `#include <Vcl.Clipbrd.hpp>` (since XE8) or `#include <Clipbrd.hpp>` (earlier versions). Note that a [separate documentation page](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Adding_the_Clipboard_Object) says you need to use `<vcl\Clipbrd.hpp>` instead. That statement is not up-to-date.

Try this:

```
#include <vcl.h>
#pragma hdrstop
#include "Unit1.h"
#include <Vcl.Clipbrd.hpp>
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#pragma package(smart_init)
#pragma resource "*.dfm"
TForm1 *Form1;

.....................

void __fastcall TForm1::Button3Click(TObject *Sender)
{
  Clipboard()->AsText=DBLookupListBox12->DataField;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, clipboard working, but I can copy DataField is property string with name of lookup field, DBLookupListBox12->Field->AsString(); giving me value of ID, not value of Lookup field.

Comment: @alex6999: Yes, I didn't read your code carefully enough. I've edited my answer.

Comment: DataField have no sense and i change DBLookupListBox12 to Clipboard()->AsText=DBLookupComboBox24->Text;

Comment: @alex6999 Your Db-related question should be asked as a separate post, it has nothing to do with this post's question about the Clipboard.  One question per post, please.

Comment: @KenWhite in modern C++Builder, you need to use `#include <Vcl.Clipbrd.hpp>` instead. Prior to XE2 introducing Unit Scopes, you could use `<Clipbrd.hpp>` or `<vcl\Clipbrd.hpp>`, but that's old. `<Clipbrd.hpp>` and `<vcl\Clipbrd.hpp>` are the same file, and just uses `<Vcl.Clipbrd.hpp>` internally for backwards compatibility. But using legacy headers was deprecated in XE8 and most legacy headers were removed in 10.1. Oddly, `<vcl\Clipbrd.hpp>` still exists in 12.0, but it does emit a compiler warning/error telling the user to use `<Vcl.Clipboard.hpp>` instead.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Thanks. I've edited my answer to include the information you provided. Did I explain it correctly?

Comment: @KenWhite  I tweaked it a little for you.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Actually, that's much better than what I had. Thanks!